# How do I get an image to show in the navbar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image to show for the background of my navigation bar, I have looked at several samples of code and examples on this site and elsewhere but, I am having little luck fixing my mistakes.

This is the markup:

```
<!--DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" type="img/png" href="Johns Cars Shadow.ico" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Johns Cars</title>
<style type="text/css">

#main {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 15px #888888;
}

</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" marginwidth="95" link="#FFFFFF">
<table id="main" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="1200" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="container" align="center" width="1200">
        <div id="logo">
            <table align="center" width="345" height="167">
                 <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                    <img src="Johns cars Shadow.png" width="341" height="167"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="cssmenu">
            <li id="active"><a href="home.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Products</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
            <li id="last"><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the css:

```
 ul.cssmenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: transparent url(../images/nav.png) repeat-x top left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
 }
ul.cssmenu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.cssmenu li a {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 color: #999999;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 8px 20px 0 20px;
}
ul.cssmenu li a:hover {
 color: #4d4d4d;
 height: 22px;
 background-image: transparent url(../images/nav.png) 0px -30px no-repeat;
}
ul.cssmenu li:active a {
 display: inline;
 height: 22px;
 background-image: transparent url(../images/nav.png) 0px -30px no-repeat;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
}
```

Any help would be welcomed!

Comment: Why is your DTD wrapped in `<!-- -->`?

Comment: For one change `../images/nav.png` to `images/nav.png`. `../` means to go up to the parent directory from where the stylesheet is located. Looking at your source code, your style.css is in your root directory, so I'm guessing your `images` folder is in the root too.
Also, you want to use `background` rather than `background-image` as you are specifying more than just the image url. 
Also, do not use tables to layout your page. And don't use tag attributes to set colour, margin, width and text alignment. This is what css is for.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions!! @3dgoo I will adjust all for all of your suggestions and the directory was the issue. I knew I was overlooking a couple of things. As for the tables and tags it is all just for a rough draft with quick and dirty. Nothing I am going to publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the property `background-image`, you can't also supply color/bgposition/bgrepeat — in this case it expects only a url to an image, so your values here are treated as invalid and ignored. `background` is the valid shorthand property that lets you set multiple properties.

```
background: transparent url(../images/nav.png) repeat-x top left;
```

Comment: Thank you for the shorthand. The directory was also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
.active {
       background:#ccc url(path/to/image/marker.png) center bottom no-repeat; 
}
```